# Using expressions as a parameter for a SQL Server function

Tags: sql, sql-server, expression

SQL Server comes with a number of string functions, such as RIGHT(), which accepts an Expression as a parameter so that it can accept either a varchar or nvarchar value.

How do I create my own custom function to do the same?

I am not a SQL Server expert, so a simple example with syntax would help.

Thank You

Comment: It looks like SQL Server has something called SQL_VARIANT.  Would this help me at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myUDF (@input nvarchar(255))
RETURNS nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
            -- function logic here
            declare @output nvarchar(255)
            select @output = 'The value passed in was: ' + @input
            return @output
End

GO    

select dbo.myUDF('I wrote a function!')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the function and it works.

However, when I look at the definition in SQL Server Mgmt Studio it indicates that the parameter is defined as an nvarchar(255).

I'm looking for a way to have that input be defined as an expression that can accept either an nvarchar OR a varchar.

Microsoft has done this for its string functions.  How do I do it?

Comment: You should be able to pass any varchar or nvarchar value into a nvarchar parameter, such as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this way.

[How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried following these instructions.  When I get to the "Add New Item" dialog box, I do not have the option of selecting a "User-defined Function."  I can select "User-defined Data Type", "User-defined Table Type", or "User-defined Type."

Comment: It looks like SQL Server has something called SQL_VARIANT. Would this help me at all?